# How to specify snakemake wrapper with relative path?

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to use some wrappers that I define in my pipeline directory (same directory as the Snakefile) rather the wrapper repo.

I have looked at the docs for this and it works fine when I use an absolute path, but I can't get a relative path to work.
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/modularization.html#wrappers

e.g. specified via absolute path, works

```
wrapper:
    "file:///Users/my_username/my_pipeline_dir/wrappers/wrapper_star-build/"
```

e.g. specified via relative path, doesn't work

```
wrapper:
   "file:/wrappers/wrapper_star-build/"
```

This is my interpretation of the formatting for a relative path according the docs. I have also tried all of the following, none of which work for me:

```
"file:wrappers/wrapper_star-build/"
"file:./wrappers/wrapper_star-build/"
"wrappers/wrapper_star-build/"
```

I am using the --directory option so that I can keep my pipeline and output organized separately.

```
snakemake --directory my_outdir/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which snakemake version are you using?

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy 5.8.1

Comment: Can you post snakemake command and error message? Wondering if you use different working directory than the one with Snakefile in it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided more detail. My goal is to have the pipeline in one directory, so that I can manage it with git, and to have my experiment-specific config file and sample sheet in a different run directory. I also use conda.

Comment: i.e.
pipe_dir$ snakemake --directory run_dir/ --use-conda
For example, I just tried using my kallisto wrapper with absolute path in the rule:
"file:///pipe_dir/wrappers/wrapper_kallisto" #runs
vs. 
"file:/wrappers/wrapper_kallisto" #doesn't run
The error message is WorkflowError:
Conda env file does not exist: /wrappers/wrapper_kallisto/environment.yaml
I'm pretty sure the docs say that the wrapper path should be relative to the snake file regardless of whether you use the --directory flag but I tried copying it to the output directory to check and it still didn't work.

Comment: If you use use `file:wrappers/wrapper_star-build/`, do you get same exact error message? Btw, proposed answer below should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently we can access the workflow.snakefile and workflow.basedir variables.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/snakemake/cp9ZbGQgaic/Vtth6fcRO6cJ

workflow.basedir is the directory where the snakefile resides.

```
snake_dir = workflow.basedir
......
wrapper:
    f"file:{snake_dir}/wrappers/wrapper_kallisto"
```

Comment: Pretty new to using stackoverflow. Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

rule star_build:
    ...
    wrapper:
        f"file:{dir_path}/wrappers/wrapper_star-build/"
```

This way we add the path in front of our relative path.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am still not getting the correct path.

dir_path, when accessed this way at the top of my snakefile, seems to be the path to my snakemake installation, not the path to my pipeline directory.
So now I get this error:
Conda env file does not exist: /Users/my_username/miniconda3/envs/pipedev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/wrappers/wrapper_star-build/environment.yaml

Sorry if I am misunderstanding something basic here. I am running it in a conda environment on a Mac, in case that is relevant.

Comment: Apparently snakemake [has built-in option](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/snakemake/cp9ZbGQgaic/Vtth6fcRO6cJ) to get snakefile's path - `srcdir`. So, it would be `srcdir/local/path/wrapper`. Also based on another comment in the same page, this works - `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__name__))`

Comment: Thanks for finding that page! It led me to a (somewhat inelegant) answer which I will describe below. Neither of these two approaches you listed worked for me though. os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__name__)) gives me the working/output directory (not the directory the snakefile is in) because I am using the --directory flag to keep my pipeline and output separate. It seems like srcdir() should work, but this actually takes me to the snakemake wrappers repo on github, which I guess snakemake considers to be the srcdir for wrappers.

Comment: @vantom Glad to be of help. Strange that `srcdir` behaved that way.